# Do the Oxygen Torches in the movie "Life" (2017) exist and how do/would they work?

Tags: realism, life

Yesterday I watched the recent movie **Life** where the ISS crew revives a life-threatening organism from Mars.

I'm usually thorough about realism of scientific elements in Sci-Fi movies, and thought the movie handled them pretty right, but **I couldn’t find any info on the Oxygen Torches they use as one-time O2 generators/burners on multiple occasions**.

Does something resembling that exists, and how does it/would it work?

The device is apparently designed to produce limited O2 for emergencies, or maybe just act as a high-tech glow-torch, and also generates a lot of heat (enough to damage the creature at an early state).

Comment: Haven't seen the film but they do have chemical O2 generators on the ISS - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vika_oxygen_generator

Comment: I've not seen it either, but they have self-igniting flares & cutting torches that work underwater, so why not in space.

Comment: That definitely looked like a blend of those two, with the principal use being a high-tech Vika generator which releases oxygen into the ISS' atmosphere.

Comment: "about realism"... I think this no-bone creature had an unrealistic extremely high strength when squeezing Hugh's hand?  And how could this creature  move outside the ship without oxygen? In the movie they explain that without oxygen the creature should enter a dormant state.

Comment: Yes... unrealistic extremely high strength than can crush a hand, but seconds later can't  tear a rubber globe.

Comment: On unrealism… I don't think anything to do with orbital mechanics is realistic in the film

Answer (score 1):

Despite not having found much information about a similar looking Oxygen Torch, I did find [this](http://www.bernzomatic.com/product/ox9-1-4-oz-oxygen-torch-cylinder/), a fuel tank for an [oxygen torch](http://www.bernzomatic.com/product/ox2550kc-cutting-welding-and-brazing-torch-kit/).

I assume that an oxygen torch in the movie is just a different-looking kind of blow-torch that uses oxygen as fuel. It matches all the 3 features you described.

- It has a compressed oxygen tank as a supply, thus is able to produce limited amounts of oxygen
- It generates light when oxygen burns
- It generates heat when oxygen burns

Comment: Did you mean to say "heat" instead of "head"?

Comment: @steelershark Erm, yeah..

Comment: Hahahaha!  Okay.  Well, I didn't want to edit it if it was already correct because I have no clue about the context here :)